# Deleting a substring from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

For destructively deleting substrings from a string by match with a regex or a string (not a character range used for `tr`), there is one way to do it:

```
string.gsub!(regex_or_string_pattern, "")
string # => ...
```

I thought this can be replaced by the following code:

```
string.slice!(regex_or_string_pattern)
string # => ...
```

However, testing them with some examples seem to indicate that they are not equivalent. When do they end up with different results?

Comment: Do you mean to be comparing `sub!` with `slice!`?  `str = "abcabc"; str.slice!("ab") #=> "ab"; str #=> "cabc"; str = "abcabc"; str.gsub!("ab",'') #=> "cc"; str #=> "cc"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I meant `gsub!`. I do make mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `gsub!` is "Global Substitution". If there are more than one matches to your string_or_regex_pattern, gsub will replace all of them with "". However `slice!` will only slice out the first match.